# Drag File to Download in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, download

I've implemented drag'n'drop file downloads for some reports in my company's intranet, but it's only currently working correctly in Chrome. In Firefox, all I get is the link dragged out rather than the file being saved. Here's the meaty bit:

```
var dragDL = function (e, filedata) {
    if (e.dataTransfer) {
        var url = filedata || (this.dataset && this.dataset.downloadurl) || this.getAttribute("data-downloadurl");
        e.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", url);
    }
};
```

**[Here's a jsFiddle with a live link in it and mostly the same code.](http://jsfiddle.net/davmillar/F5L6r/)** *(For some reason, the fiddle version doesn't work in Chrome either — not sure if it's a cross-domain issue?)*

Can anyone lend some insight into what I'm doing wrong? I'm finding next to nothing on this when Googling for it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `DownloadURL` is a non-standard feature.
It is invented by the Chrome developers.